# NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() not work on JDK 1.7 OS X?

Tags: java

Running the following code, I got a `SocketException`:

```
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class interfaces {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> inters = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface iface : Collections.list(inters)) {
            System.out.println(iface.getDisplayName());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using OS X 10.8.2 with JDK 1.7.0_09-b05.

It works well on Windows with THIS JDK VERSION, and also well on OS X with JDK 1.6.
Can anybody help me to test this and check if it's a bug of JDK?

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.net.SocketException: Can't assign requested address
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll(Native Method)
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.java:334)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace for your exception.

Comment: I'm running java 1.7.0_09-b05 on OSX 10.8.2. Works for me.

Comment: Works on Max OSX 10.7.4 with OpenJDK 7 (build 1.7.0_04-ea-b11).

Comment: @DiegoBasch Thanks a lot. Could you please give me some suggestions to fix it?

Comment: @Brian Here is trace:Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Can't assign requested address
 at java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll(Native Method)
 at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.java:334)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue that was caused by an ipv6 address being returned from `java.net.NetworkInterface.getDefault()`.  I'm on a Macbook and was using wireless -- p2p0 (used for AirDrop) was returned as the default but mine only has an ipv6 `ether` entry when running `ipconfig` (no `inet`).

Two solutions, both of which worked for me (I prefer the first)

1. Start your JVM with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.  This caused `java.net.NetworkInterface.getDefault()` to return my vboxnet0 network interface -- not sure what you'll get if you're not running a host-only VM.
2. Turn off wireless and use a wired connection